# fixed point conversion from a real variable in vhdl

Tags: vhdl, fixed-point

I have the following code snippet in vhdl:

```
signal s: signed(31 downto 0);
s <= to_signed(to_sfixed(1.2,8,-23),32);
```

Now I am expecting the fixed point version of 1.2 to be available in the signal 's'.

But it always neglects the fraction part. The 's' just contains the decimal part(here "1").

What am I missing here?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you just want to reinterpret the bits from the sfixed to as signed type, just use a simple type conversion:

```
signal s: signed(31 downto 0);
...
s <= signed(to_sfixed(1.2,8,-23));
```

Comment: awesome thanks.. just as a side note, for the back conversion you can use this:  r <= to_real(to_sfixed(std_logic_vector(s),8,-23)); where r is a real type.

Comment: Doing it this way, *you* have to keep track of the binary point.  It'd be better (IMHO) to keep to `sfixed` all the way through and let the compiler keep track of it.  If the destination is *really* out of your control, then you have no choice but to manage it.  I'd make sure I created some constants for the `8` and `-23` in case you want to change them in future though.

Comment: I agree with Martin that using the right types to represent your data all the way through the design is the best way to do it. On the other hand, you often have to interface with designs that don't do it this way, and it's good to know how to convert between different representations. =)

Answer (score 1):

`s` doesn't have anywhere to store any fractional part, it's a signed vector which can only represent integers.

You're nearly there though - drop the signedness and make s and sfixed type:

```
signal s: sfixed(8 downto -23);
s <= to_sfixed(1.2,sfixed'high,sfixed'low);
```

Comment: But the problem is that I am using this signal as an input to a module where 's' should be of signed format. since fixed_pkg is not synthesisable in many platforms I am using it only in the testbench code.

Comment: fixed_pkg should be synthesisable just fine.  If you can;t use it, you'll have to shift the sfixed value and keep track of where the binary point is yourself...